# Proper way to utilize macro in PHP for __FILENAME__ in called function

Tags: php, codeigniter, macros, phpunit

I'm working with PHPUnit inside CodeIgniter and have created a support method that allows me to dynamically dump my output to a file named after the invoking function with the file stored in a directory tree identical to the path of the invoking file.

The function is working wonderfully (implemented from within CIUnit_TestCase) and currently is invoked as such:

```
$this->dumpOutputToFile($out, __FILE__, __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__);
```

I would far rather be doing something along the lines of

```
$this->dumpOutputToFile($out);
```

or even (though still somewhat hacky)

```
$this->dumpOutputToFile($out, $this);
```

The problem is that within the "dumpOutputToFile()" method the magic macros no longer exist (of course) and unfortunately using debug_backtrace() is not of any help as from inside the values returned do not include the 'file' or 'line' attributes (though they are available outside the call.)

So what I'm looking for the the *cleanest/simplest* way to implement the call to dumpOutputToFile() with as little use of parameters, etc.

Macro would be fine but those aren't available.  Use of debug_backtrace would be fine but it is not providing the proper information from within.  I've also heard that XDebug thing make things a little simpler for me along these lines but I've not yet had bandwidth to install that.

Here is an example of code that I'm using inside the function to access the values:

```
$myDbg = debug_backtrace();
print "Printing array keys 'inside' ({$myDbg[0]['function']}) function:\n";
print_r(array_keys($myDbg['0']));

print "\n\nPrinting array keys to 'parent' ({$myDbg[1]['function']}) function:\n";
print_r(array_keys($myDbg['1']));
```

And the results I'm getting... the values I'm wanting are not available for the calling function:

```
Printing array keys 'inside' (dumpOutputToFile) function:
Array
(
    [0] => file
    [1] => line
    [2] => function
    [3] => class
    [4] => object
    [5] => type
    [6] => args
)

Printing array keys to 'parent' (testIndex) function:
Array
(
    [0] => function
    [1] => class
    [2] => object
    [3] => type
    [4] => args
)
```

Comment: Why doesn't debug_backtrace work? It seems to work for me.

Comment: debug_backtrace for me for some reason is not providing 'file' or 'class' from within the call to dumpOutputToFile().  It does provide those values outside the call but from within the call itself those values are not returned by debug_backtrace.

Comment: And just to be explicit $this is the class CIUnit_TestCase which is a CodeIgniter wrap around for PHPUnit which it uses to encapsulate/control the testbed.  It's a standard class but there are a lot of moving parts here and I know much less about CodeIgniter / PHPUnit than I do PHP

Comment: Can you show a dump of what debug_backtrace provides?

Comment: Sure... I went ahead and added sample output to my posting above

Comment: My thot was that maybe there was an extra/dummy/bogus function call in the list for some unknown reason, but without the values of `$myDbg` I can't tell if that is happening.